# Mongoose not saving data according to a function (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

Today, I decided to make a Discord RPG bot which of course requires profile stats such as coins and the actual users. Therefore, I searched up a [tutorial on how I can do this with MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfOOTBEwoIg) but I am running into one issue. When a guild member joins and the bot is running, the data does not save with no error at all and I am unsure of why this is happening. I have tried troubleshooting the connection status by adding a line `console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)` after the bot attempts to connect to the database. This returns `1` which means the connection is fine. I cannot find any other reason why this is caused so I decided to ask a question after hours of thinking.

(index.js): Connecting to the database

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_SERVER, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => [
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB Database successfully!"),
    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)
]).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

(profileSchema.js): Creating a profile schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
    serverid: { type: String, require: true },
    coins: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    bank: { type: Number }
});

const model = mongoose.model("ProfileModels", profileSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

(guildMemberAdd.js): Creating and uploading the data into the database

```
const profileModel = require('../models/profileSchema');

module.exports = async(client, discord, member) => {
    let profile = await profileModel.create({
        id: member.id,
        serverid: member.guild.id,
        coins: 0,
        bank: 0
    })

    profile.save();
}
```

Comment: Where is the function from guildMemberAdd.js actually called?

Comment: It's in a folder called events. This is in index.js to run when the bot comes online: https://pastebin.com/TUd240Dz Also reading your comment I decided to add ```console.log(1)``` in the function but it seems like it isn't running for some reason @Joe

Answer (score 0):

The reason is to do with the way you connect to mongo

BY default mongo closes the connection after connecting to a database. To do this, when connecting to mongo pass in the `keepAlive` option, so it would look something like:

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_SERVER, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    keepAlive: true
})
```

This will then mean an active connection to your database will be kept open

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, unfortuantely, my code still has the same issue. Do you have any other possible fixes?

Comment: Try adding an await to ``profile.save()``

Comment: doesn't work sadly.

Comment: Im not too sure then whats causing your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting 'model' from profileSchema.js and requiring 'profileModel ' from guildMemberAdd.js?
so import model from profileSchema and not profileModel

Answer (score 0):

Fix: Make sure the `guildMemberAdd` event is being called by adding `console.log` statements.

If not, check if `guildMemberAdd`'s code is different to other event codes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).